# How do i get my simple point to line calculator to work (in javascript)

Tags: javascript, math

im experienced in python but not javascript
the # represent the numbers i would put in

```
let r
let m2
let b2
let x2
let y2
function rcirc(x,y,m,b) {
  m2 = -1/m
  b2 = y - (m * x)
  y2 = (b2 - b) / (m - m2)
  x2 = (y2 - b) / m
  return(x,y)
};

rcirc("#","#","#","#");
console.log(x,",",y);
```

Comment: you have `return (x,y)` but don't modify `x` or `y` in the function

Comment: `rcirc` return value x and y. 

In your `rcirc` function you would are not setting value x and y.

Set the value and return it.

Comment: We cannot know which values to pass to this function. That is really for you to decide.

Comment: I believe that you should first learn how Javascript works and maybe functions in general, because I don't believe that it would work even in Python. `x` and `y` are arguments of the function, they do not exist outside the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have those global variables -- that wouldn't even work in Python. Define them in the function as local variables.

A difference with Python is that there is no concept of tuple in JavaScript, so you would return the values as an array (i.e. a list in Python). But of course, you should return the *result* of the calculation, not the input values!

Here is how it could look:

```js
function rcirc(x, y, m, b) {
  let m2 = -1/m;
  let b2 = y - (m * x);
  let y2 = (b2 - b) / (m - m2);
  let x2 = (y2 - b) / m;
  return [x2, y2];
}

let point = rcirc(1, 2, 3, 4);
console.log(point);
```

Answer (score 0):

While returning the pair in the function, [ ] must be used instead of ( ). Also, the new/calculated value [x2,y2] must be returned.

Also, the returned value must be stored in a variable or pair as per your wish.

```
let r
let m2
let b2
let x2
let y2
function rcirc(x,y,m,b) {
  m2 = -1/m
  b2 = y - (m * x)
  y2 = (b2 - b) / (m - m2)
  x2 = (y2 - b) / m
  return [x2,y2]
};

let [x,y] = rcirc(1,2,3,4);
console.log(x,y);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).